# Using await in Subscription: What will happen if subscription fires new event, but async action is not finished yet in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, observable, subscription

I have a subscription which continously fires events. Within this, I need to process whatever comes up from the subscription. The processing is async. There is no way I can rewrite this not async.

```
// pseudocode

SomeSubscripton.onEvent(async event => {
    ...
    await someAsyncFunction(event);
    ...
}
```

Now, I wonder what happens if `someAsyncFunction()` is not finished yet, but `SomeSubscripton.onEvent()` fires another time. Will this event be simply `ignored` or is there some kind of internal line created, that is worked down one by one by `someAsyncFunction()`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the onEvent, probably you could have a dedicated feature for that, but what I recommend for solving your issue is to implement a queue mechanism.

```
// pseudocode
treatingEvent = false;
queue = [];

SomeSubscripton.onEvent(async event => {
    ...
    if (treatingEvent) {
        queue.push(event);
        return;
    }
    treatingEvent = true;

    await someAsyncFunction(event);
    await treatQueue();
    ...
}

treatQueue = () => {
    for (event of queue) {
        someAsyncFunction(event);
    }

    queue.remove(event);

    if (queue.length)
       treatQueue();
    else
       treatingEvent = false;
};
```

Comment: Of course you can pass your treatQueue to treat async statement as well, but it was just for the concept.